# Who is the man from U.N.C.L.E.?

Tags: the-man-from-u.n.c.l.e

I just watched Guy Ritchie's [The man from U.N.C.L.E.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638355/?ref_=nv_sr_1), but since the U.N.C.L.E. team was officially formed on the end of the movie, I didn't get it; *who was the man from U.N.C.L.E.?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Title "The Man from U.N.C.L.E." refers to Napoleon Solo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_Solo). The movie is a reboot/prequel of the 1960's show of the same name.

> Solo is Number One in Section Two (Operations and Enforcement) at U.N.C.L.E. (During the show's black & white first season, the number on his official badge was the Roman numeral 'II,' signifying that he was the head of Section Two. But when the show went to color the following season, Vaughn picked up the new colored badge with "11" on it, and the mistake was never corrected.) It was originally intended that Solo would be the primary focus of the series, however the unexpected popularity of the Russian agent, Illya Kuryakin, played by David McCallum, saw McCallum elevated to co-star status.

*Of course, they could have named the movie "The Man who will become The Man from U.N.C.L.E." but that sounds ridiculous.*